# Is there any way we can call the input value that I have stored in one method to other which i will create for Output display

Tags: java, methods

I am a beginner in coding. I was trying to get the input value that I have saved in an array to the other method so that I will get the out put at the end.

Could some please help me so that I can get further?

This is my code

```
public class Functions {

            public static void input() {
                int Rows = 5;
                int Col = 2;

                String table[][] = new String[Rows][Col];

                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                for (int A = 0; A < Rows; A++) {
                    for (int P = 0; P < Col; P++) {
                        if (P == 0)
                            System.out.println("Emp Name :");
                        else
                            System.out.println("ID :");
                        table[A][P] = input.next();

                    }
public static void output(){
    System.out.println(table[A][P]);
}


}
```

I want to create two methods that I will be going to call in the main class. One in input where I will be taking input values of Employee name and Employee ID. Saved the input values in array A P. now when if i need to call the saved input method in other method named as output, so that we just run the main method by calling both these methods and we will get the values entered as table at the end as output. Is there any way we can do so ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for fields. [Here's](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/fields.html) a tutorial on fields.
Here I made the code compile and made output access table but I recommend reading a book on java or a basic tutorial so that you understand fields and the static keyword etc.

```
public class Functions {

    private static String table[][];
    private static int Rows = 5;
    private static int Col = 2;

    public static void input() {

        table = new String[Rows][Col];

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int A = 0; A < Rows; A++) {
            for (int P = 0; P < Col; P++) {
                if (P == 0)
                    System.out.println("Emp Name :");
                else
                    System.out.println("ID :");
                table[A][P] = input.next();

            }
        }
    }

    public static void output(){
        for (int A = 0; A < Rows; A++) {
            for (int P = 0; P < Col; P++) {
                System.out.println(table[A][P]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Simon for your inputs.. :)